# Probability of reception from n users

Tags: statistics

Say I have 4 boxes on the ground. At every time interval the nth user(n = 1,2,3...) has some probability of throwing 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 balls into the boxes. Each box can only hold one ball, and the probability of throwing each ball is p0 for 0, p1 for 1, p2 for 2, p3 for 3, and p4 for 4. p0+p1+p2+p3+p4 = 100% and p0, p1, p2, p3, p4 are constant. If the boxes each have a ball in them, any subsequent balls will bounce off and be lost. Closer throwers' balls always land in the boxes before subsequent users. So my question is what is the probability that the nth user will be able to land at least 1 ball in a box after m tries. My first instinct is to use a Poisson distribution, but I have a feeling it's not quite appropriate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  What's $A$?  I mean, what event is $A$ the probability of?

Comment: The probability that a user throws any balls at all. I suppose it would be equivalent to saying if A =.3 and p1 = .5, p2=.3, p3= .15, p4 = .05 then p0 (the probability that the user doesn't throw anything) becomes p0=.7 and p1 = .3*.5=.15 p2 = .09 p3 = .045 p4 = .015?

Comment: So, first the user flips a weighted coin to decide whether to play or not.  If he decides to play then each ball is thrown with the indicated probabilities?  I take it that each user has the same probabilities and that ball $i$ can only go in box $i$?

Comment: Nope, still not getting it even after the edit.  Let's use your numbers, so $\{p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ are $\{.7,.15,.09,.045,.015\}$.  I'm the first user and I get event $p_2$, so I guess I am throwing $2$ balls?  Where do they go?  If the second user gets event $p_3$, is the game over?  All boxes filled?

Comment: Yep you've pretty much got it, it doesn't matter where the balls go up to 4, they can randomly fill the boxes. In your example user 1 fills 2 boxes, and user 2 fills 2 boxes while one of his balls bounces off and is lost. Any subsequent user in that timeframe would also lose all their balls, so only users 1 and 2 were received.

If there is still an unfilled box a ball will go in it, so I guess think about it as 1 box will only room for 4 balls.

Comment: Ok...but then, in order for there to be an empty box available for the $n^{th}$ user, the total number of balls thrown has to be $T_{n-1}<4$.  So, just go case by case.  If $T_{n-1}=0$ then everyone threw $0$ balls, easy!  If $T_{n-1}=1$ then exactly one person threw one ball, still easy!  Slightly more complex for $2,3$ but case by case still works.

Comment: I'm starting to think my Poisson distribution idea would be correct. Calculate lambda as the average number of balls thrown by n-1 users and then k =4 is the probability that I will not be received? Recalculating lambda for each n essentially.

Or rather the sum of k=4...4(n-1).

Comment: Too complex.  The exact calculation is easy enough.  There are so few cases!

Comment: Once I get up to many users (say 20) doesn't that become tedious?

Comment: I know.  So what?  $4$ is so small.  Worst case for you to compute is if $3$ balls have been thrown.  But the only ways for that to happen are: $(1,0,0,n-2),(0,1,1,n-3),(0,0,3,n-4)$  where the notation $(a,b,c,d)$ means that $a$ users threw $3$ balls, $b$ threw $2$, $c$ threw $1$, $d$ threw $0$.

Comment: the number of users isn't terribly relevant.  You can replace the factorials that arise with Stirling's approximation.  The number of boxes is more relevant.  If you want a large number of boxes instead of $4$ you'll want some sort of approximation to the multinomial distribution.